# Range slider, left value always less than right value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I have range slider. I need that left value always be less than right value. 
For example, if i have values = [3, 4] than slider have to disable moving to state [3, 3] or [4,4]

```
<div id="slider-range" style="width: 200px; margin: 20px auto;"></div>

$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        values: [ 3, 5],
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmsWJ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare on the fly your current values and return false if :

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmsWJ/4/)**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        values: [ 3, 5 ],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.values[0] >= ui.values[1] ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```